# Multiple classes with same properties but different types

Tags: c#, class, oop

I want to create a class that has the same field names as another class but with different field types.
for example:

```
public class Core
{
    public float Temperature { get; private set; }
    public float Load { get; private set; }
    public float Clock { get; private set; }

...
```

I got the above class and i want another class that has all the fields but in boolean type.

```
public class CoreThreshold
{
    public bool Temperature { get; private set; }
    public bool Load { get; private set; }
    public bool Clock { get; private set; }
...
```

The way I did it is hard-coded like the above and wondered if there is a better way.

I want to make it OOP accessible and not with a method that gets a string and returns the value.
Also just to make the float value either 1 or 0 like boolean is not an option (the actual type is not float).

Could it be done, or the only option is to hard-code every detail across the two classes?

Comment: The term to look up is generics.

Comment: Are you just trying to avoid writing property declarations or is there any other relationship between the classes in question?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yeah, I came to realize after mentioning generics that they might not be the right tool here (we don't want to end up writing something like a class TooGeneric<S,T,U> with public fields X,Y,Z of types S,T,U).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft yeah it's a tricky problem. Part of me is thinking that it is an improper use of inheritance, but part of me finds it very useful to be able to create types this way in languages like TypeScript. Then again, in TypeScript, it is only useful because of structural typing which doesn't apply here.

Comment: Unless your example is very bad, this seems like a terrible violation of object oriented programming. A property named `Temperature` should be the same in every class.

Comment: Tell us what you want to achieve. Why do the field need to have the same name as in base? Name them TemperatureTreshold and so on...
You could also make the filed type `object`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this will do what you hope it will, but I am going to take a shot in the dark.

You could have a base class that supports `Generic`. For example:

```
public abstract class BaseCore<T>
{
    public T Temperature { get; protected set; }
    public T Load { get; protected set; }
    public T Clock { get; protected set; }
}
```

Then derive some classes based on that:

```
public class Core : BaseCore<float>
{
}

public class CoreThreshold : BaseCore<bool>
{
}
```

So, you all you have to do is add another property to `BaseCore` and all derived classes will automatically get it. You don't have to duplicate code.

Comment: well, I feel quite dumb now because I knew about generics, but thank you for the help.